# ImageMagick: dyld: Library not loaded. Reason: image not found

Tags: macos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, dyld

1. I downloaded ImageMagick from https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx
2. extracted it to ~/Documents/software
3. my `.profile` looks like this:

> ```
> export MAGICK_HOME="~/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7"
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
> export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
> ```

4. when I run `convert` I get:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /ImageMagick-7.0.7/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Users/oa/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7/bin/convert
>   Reason: image not found
>   Abort trap: 6

Comment: Any reason not to use **homebrew**? It is miles easier to manage all your packages that way - i.e. `brew install imagemagick` and you are done.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, but the reason being I want to get to the bottom of this annoying error.

Comment: First, try using `$HOME` instead of `~` as that works in more shells. Second, try using `otool -L /Users/oa/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7/bin/convert` to see what your `convert` binary actually needs/wants. Also, try `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH=1 convert ...` to debug dynamic link libraries. Finally, resort to **homebrew** ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell you just solved the error! Thank man.

Comment: Pleasure! Feel free to write up the bit that helped and put it as an answer for all to see. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by @Mark Setchell, the solution was to replace `~` by `$HOME`. Therefore, the export commands should be:

```
export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not use brew, using otool -L  shows the problem:

```sh
    /ImageMagick-7.0.10/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /ImageMagick-7.0.10/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 19.0.0, current version 19.6.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 43.0.0, current version 43.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 904.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.1.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libICE.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
```